# Recovering files from corrupted Flash Drive

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, 21.04

So I have a 64GB SanDisk Cruzer Glide, and recently something happened to it. Whenever I would try to fsck it said the magic number for the superblock was corrupted, I didn't know what that meant, so I backed up everything with `dd` to a 1TB hard drive.

I formatted it as exFAT in macOS, and put it back into my Ubuntu computer. I tried to mount the .img file to a directory I made so I can try to copy the files over to the thumb drive, so I can then copy them to my hard drive, but whenever I try to mount the .img file, I get this...

```
root@ubuntu:/home/wolfyn_claw# mkdir /mnt/glide2
root@ubuntu:/home/wolfyn_claw# mount -o loop '/media/wolfyn_claw/AC_STORAGE/glide2.img' /mnt/glide2
mount: /mnt/glide2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop17, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I'm attempting to write the .img file back to the thumb drive and see how that goes. I'm really hoping I can access the files on it, I can't afford to lose any of it.

[image]

I'll edit this and add more information when I try to fsck the thumb drive after the writing is complete.

Comment: DO NOT DELETE ORIGINAL! The new version will not be ext4!

Comment: That is what happened [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348436/luks-drive-i-can-unlock-but-not-mount/1348612#1348612). The launcher broke the  partition trying to repair the superblock. We spent hours trying to get it fixed, and never did.

Comment: I created an .img file from /dev/sda and /dev/sda1

Comment: So I have two 65GB .img files

Comment: ```
That is what happened here. The launcher broke the partition trying to repair the superblock. We spent hours trying to get it fixed, and never did.
```

So does this mean everything is gone?

Comment: Try accessing w/ gparted in gui mode. Does result look like picture in linked question.? Did it mnt?

Comment: /dev/sdc1 (!) Unknown     59.16GiB

Comment: I changed operating systems from UM to ubuntu, so the thumb drive is sdc1 instead of sda1.

Comment: I can access it in Gparted, but the filesystem is unknown.

Comment: Have you tried using dd on the original to change back to ext4? That may mount. Pipe it through `tee` to a copy first, so you aren't risking anything.

Comment: No. OP didn't save the original.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127338/discussion-between-achak-claw-and-nate-t).